What is an industry standard name for this self-referencing foreign key relationship?
I'm currently in a battle with Entity Framework over trying to make a self-referencing relationship without having to add additional columns/properties. I have confirmed the foreign key I envision is possible in SQL Server, but it is difficult to research possible solutions because I keep finding generic single-column foreign keys.
Is there some widely used term specific to this form of self-referencing, composite foreign key?
create table LookupValues
(
    LookupName            nvarchar(255)             not null,
    ExternalRefCode       nvarchar(255) default N'' not null,
    ParentExternalRefCode nvarchar(255),
    
    constraint PK_LookupValues
        primary key (LookupName, ExternalRefCode)
)

alter table LookupValues
    add constraint CompositeFK
        foreign key (LookupName, ParentExternalRefCode) references LookupValues

The idea behind it is that although there are multiple values for LookupName in this table, there will never be cross-value relationships in the parent/child relationships. e.g. a child from LookupName: A must belong to a parent from LookupName: A.
I've tried searches like "self-referencing composite foreign key", "self-referencing foreign key using part of primary key", and "composite foreign key with common column in primary key", etc.

Looks like you are heading for the "One True Lookup Table" anti pattern?

@MartinSmith Sadly, this table is an internal representation of a third party system that I've been tasked with integrating with. I want the relationship in our table to match so that I can better traverse the hierarchy of values and run some evaluations on them. I'm very displeased with this system overall

There probably isn't an industry standard term for the key feature you are asking about (partitioning by LookupName) as these should just be in their own table if you need that.

With a visual and more descriptive usage (manager_id relates with employee_id)

those type of relations usually called as a self-referencing relationship but
also known as a recursive relationship
